Why running laravel/sail project for the second time I got error with unknown database?
Yesterday I installed sail into exiting laravel app and tried it working:
But today running in the project :
hoster@hoster-os:/path/ProjectName$ ./vendor/bin/sail up
[+] Running 2/0
✔ Container ProjectDB-mysql-1         Running                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
✔ Container ProjectDB-laravel.test-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
Attaching to laravel.test-1, mysql-1
laravel.test-1  | usermod: no changes
laravel.test-1  | 2024-12-24 07:54:55,091 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
laravel.test-1  | 2024-12-24 07:54:55,094 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
laravel.test-1  | 2024-12-24 07:54:56,097 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 9
laravel.test-1  |   PHP Warning:  JIT is incompatible with third party extensions that override zend_execute_ex(). JIT disabled. in Unknown on line 0
laravel.test-1  |
laravel.test-1  |    INFO  Server running on [http://0.0.0.0:80].
laravel.test-1  |
laravel.test-1  |   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
laravel.test-1  |
laravel.test-1  | 2024-12-24 07:54:57,974 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
laravel.test-1  |   2024-12-24 07:55:20 / ................................................ ~ 1s
laravel.test-1  |   2024-12-24 07:55:20 .............................................. ~ 1m 31s
laravel.test-1  |   2024-12-24 07:57:21 / ................................................ ~ 2s
laravel.test-1  |   2024-12-24 08:02:26 .............................................. ~ 0.49ms

I got error in the browser with url http://0.0.0.0:80:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ProjectDB' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = MWLBw35TjWKQ8CayuoseHuJTspz9FyPBKLAS9MkZ limit 1)

I tried to run command I found at docs at https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sail in the root of the project:
hoster@hoster-os:/path/ProjectName$ sail artisan migrate
Command 'sail' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install bsdgames

I suppose that sail was running and in another tab of the console I got error ?
Yesterday I did not have this error. Seems I stopped that sessions table uin the db was not found...
"php": "^8.2",
"laravel/framework": "^11.31",
"laravel/sail": "^1.39",

Thanks in advance!

This is clearly the issue of sessions table.chcek whether it is exist and also chcek the Db ProjectDB cooncetion details in the .env.

As Subha pointed out, your database does not exist. Try running ./vendor/bin/sail php artisan migrate

If you want to just use sail you need to alias it. Also as a general rule, Laravel will not create your database schema for you, that you'd need to do manually
